# wordpress docker cannot connect to mysql docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

Not sure what I am doing wrong but my wordpress docker just does not connect to the mysql docker.  Can someone help me here please?

```
version: '2'
services: 
db:  
  image: mysql:8.0
  container_name: eve_db
  volumes:
    - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./database/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: skdjd           # any random string will do
    MYSQL_DATABASE: djdjd                # the name of your mysql database
    MYSQL_USER: djdjd                    # the name of the database user
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: djdjd                # the password of the mysql user
wordpress:
  depends_on:
    - db
  image: wordpress:php7.2                   # we're using the image with php7.1
  container_name: eve_de
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  restart: always
  links:
    - db:mysql
  volumes:
    - ./src/wp:/var/www/html
```

I have also defined

> define('DB_HOST', 'db:3306');

in the wp-config.php file.  But it did not work.

Comment: if you log in into the wordpress container, could you ping the mysql container?

Comment: Yes.  It can ping.

Comment: you ping using `ping eve_db` ?

Comment: I installed mysql-client and tried to connect manually to the db.  It gives below error:  root@def23e496b9a:/var/www/html# mysql -h eve_db -u djdjd -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: On the container running mysql, run `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` then restart the container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main site was having mysql v5.6.38.  Changing the same in docker-compose.yml solved the issue.